# How can I attach the Android back button to a specific navigator?

Tags: flutter

I have a bottom navigation bar that creates a navigator for each of the apps main screens.

Problem: When I go down a level in one of the nested navigators and then press the back button on Android it closes the app. I guess that's because the global navigator of the main screen, that holds the bottom navigation bar, only has this one screen on the stack.

Desired behavior: The Android back button pops the nested navigator instead of the global one.

How can I attach the Android back button to a specific navigator?

Edit: Here a working minimal example.

If I go to settings 2, I can go back to settings 1 using the back button in the app bar, but when I use the Android back button the app closes.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.book),
              title: Text("Book"),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              title: Text("Settings"),
            )
          ],
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onTap: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedIndex = index;
            });
          }),
      body: SafeArea(
        top: false,
        child: IndexedStack(
          index: _selectedIndex,
          children: <Widget>[
            Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text("Book"),
              ),
            ),
            SettingsNavigator(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SettingsNavigator extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingsNavigatorState createState() => _SettingsNavigatorState();
}

class _SettingsNavigatorState extends State<SettingsNavigator> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            settings: settings,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              switch (settings.name) {
                case '/':
                  return Settings1();
                case '/settings2':
                  return Settings2();
              }
            });
      },
    );
  }
}

class Settings1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Settings 1"),
      ),
      body: FlatButton(
        child: Text("Go to settings 2"),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/settings2'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Settings2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Settings 2"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got to the source of the problem. No matter where I put the `WillPopScope` in the code from the question, it would not get triggered. The problem was that I was using an `IndexedStack` which is wrapped in a `Scaffold`, but the pages in the stack are also wrapped in scaffolds. The solution was to remove the scaffolds from the pages on the stack. Pressing the android back button now calls the `onWillPop` of the single scaffold. From there the currently active nested navigator can be popped or otherwise the app gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

As no code is provided, I can give you an idea of how you can achieve this (from the understanding of question). You can use willPopScope which will execute whenever something tries to popScope of the current widget rest you can google it.As it would require a visual explanation.

Comment: I added an example. Where would I need to put WillPopScope in your opinion? If I put it around the scaffold of Settings2, it doesn't get called and the app still closes.

Comment: use this line onWillPop: () async => false, and then put child as your root widget which you don't want to pop. Using the above line will not pop your scope until you explicitly specify.Use the above line in WillPopScope widget. willPopScope have a property onWillPop:.

Comment: No matter what I wrap with that, the callback does not get triggered. Does it get triggered for you when running the example?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution!!**

There must be a problem with your routes: Here Alternate Solution for you

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: BottomWidget(),
      routes: {
        Settings2.route_name: (ctx) => Settings2(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class BottomWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomWidgetState createState() => _BottomWidgetState();
}

class _BottomWidgetState extends State<BottomWidget> {
  int _cIndex = 0;

  void _incrementTab(index) {
    print("inxed ${index}");
    setState(() {
      _cIndex = index;
    });
  }

  Widget navigateToWidget() {
    switch (_cIndex) {
      case 0:
        return HomeScreen();
      case 1:
        return Settings1();
        break;
    }
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _cIndex,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.book),
            title: Text("Book"),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            title: Text("Settings"),
          )
        ],
        onTap: (index) {
          _incrementTab(index);
        },
      ),
      body: navigateToWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Book'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Home Screen'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Settings1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Settings 1"),
      ),
      body: FlatButton(
        child: Text("Go to settings 2"),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Settings2.route_name),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Settings2 extends StatelessWidget {
  static final route_name = "\Settings2";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Settings 2"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I understand your code correctly, that will navigate between the tabs of the bottom navigation bar, but that's not what I want to do. Have a look at my code example.

Comment: @Mr-Pepe: Go through an alternate solutions.